# Why is my laptop screen dim after resume from screen-lock, sleep, or suspend?

Tags: nvidia, suspend, power-management, brightness

After every resume from screen-lock, sleep, or suspend, my laptop screen is very dim. If I type <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, then the screen jumps to 100% brightness instantly. (<kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> are my brightness control keys.)

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ lspci -nnk | grep -EA3 VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:25b8] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:22d8]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nouveau latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:410-40f irq:199 memory:ab000000-abffffff memory:4000000000-40ffffffff memory:4100000000-4101ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ac080000-ac0fffff

$ sudo lshw | grep -i lenovo
    product: 20YU002HUS (LENOVO_MT_20YU_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad P17 Gen 2i)
    vendor: LENOVO
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled chassis=notebook family=ThinkPad P17 Gen 2i power-on_password=disabled sku=LENOVO_MT_20YU_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad P17 Gen 2i uuid=4C043C28-3F2B-B211-A85C-940FFC06910B
       vendor: LENOVO
          vendor: LENOVO
```

---

**Before screen-lock, sleep, or suspend:**

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/actual_brightness 
100
```

[image: Power Settings Before]
[image: Brightness Setting Before]

**After screen-lock, sleep, or suspend:**

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/actual_brightness 
33
```

[image: Power Settings After]
[image: Brightness Setting After]

---

I'm entering lock mode by any of the following:

- By inactivity
- From command line with: `xdg-screensaver lock`
- From drop-down menu by clicking: `Lock`

I'm entering sleep/suspend mode by any of the following:

- From command line with: `systemctl suspend`
- From drop-down menu by clicking: `Power Off/Log Out` > `Suspend`

Take note that after resume from lock/sleep/suspend, the content of `/sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/actual_brightness` is `33`, not `100`.

To achieve full brightness again, I only have to type <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> once. I find this a bit odd, because typically, if the brightness is that low, it would take several key presses. For example, to go from `30` to `100`, it would normally be seven key presses.

Also, you'll notice in the `Settings/Power` window that the brightness level indicates it's at 100%, both before and after lock/sleep/suspend.

Finally, you'll notice that I have the setting, `Dim Screen When Inactive`, disabled.

---

In my attempt to come up with some sort of solution, I installed `xbacklight` with the idea that I could use it in a script to automatically reset my brightness. But this had no affect.

I also attempted the following commands, but the brightness levels don't change, and I'm unable to write to the file. Perhaps this is the wrong approach.

```
$ sudo chmod 644 /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/actual_brightness

$ sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/actual_brightness <<< 100
100
tee: /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/actual_brightness: Input/output error

$ sudo su

# echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/actual_brightness
bash: echo: write error: Input/output error
```

---

Why is this symptom happening, and how do I fix it? Ideally, I would prefer to not incorporate a script that runs at login. This seems like treating the symptom and not the cause.

---

### UPDATE

I attempted the two following suggested solutions, but neither worked.

**Suggestion 1 - Systemd service**

- Create file:

  ```
   $ cat /etc/systemd/system/nvidia-backlight-sleep

   [Unit]
   Description=Fix Nvidia backlight after suspend
   Before=sleep.target
   StopWhenUnneeded=yes

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   RemainAfterExit=yes
   ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "cat /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/actual_brightness > /run/previous_nv_backlight_brightness"
   ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "sleep 1; cat /run/previous_nv_backlight_brightness > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness"

   [Install]
   WantedBy=sleep.target
  ```
- Reload systemd daemons: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
- Enable service: `sudo systemctl enable nvidia-backlight-sleep`

**Suggestion 2 - Create script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep`**

- Create file:

  ```
   $ cat /lib/systemd/system-sleep/nvidia-backlight-sleep

   #!/bin/bash

   case $1 in
     post)
       sleep 1
       echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
       ;;
   esac
  ```
- Make executable: `sudo chmod 755 /lib/systemd/system-sleep/nvidia-backlight-sleep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by switching from the open-source `nouveau` driver to the proprietary `nvidia-driver-535`. This can be installed from either the command line or through the GUI. I chose to install it through the GUI.

1. In *Activities*, search for “*driver*” and click on “*Additional Drivers*” icon.
   [image]
2. The “*Software & Updates*” window will open to the "*Additional Drivers*" tab.
   [image]
3. I selected "*Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-535 (proprietary)*" and clicked on "*Apply Changes*"
   [image]
4. I rebooted computer

---

After a reboot, you can see that the Nvidia driver is in use:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:410-40f irq:200 memory:ab000000-abffffff memory:4000000000-40ffffffff memory:4100000000-4101ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ac080000-ac0fffff
```

Additionally, along with the installation of the driver, a utility called `nvidia-settings` is installed. Run that with `sudo nvidia-settings` and the following window displays:
[image]

Another utility app that is installed with the Nvidia driver is System Management Interface, `nvidia-sma`:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Tue Feb 27 21:32:15 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.161.07             Driver Version: 535.161.07   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX A2000 Laptop GPU    Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   38C    P8               7W /  60W |    411MiB /  4096MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1344      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           39MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2153      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          114MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2282      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         83MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7710      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                    153MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Finally, I can lock or suspend my laptop and the screen backlight brightness settings are retained. Whereas before the value was saved in `/sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/actual_brightness`, the new driver saves the value in `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/actual_brightness`:

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/actual_brightness 
100
```

---

In conclusion, I think that there's a bug with the `nouveau` driver that is incorrectly saving and recalling the `actual_brightness` value. For some reason, it always resumed from lock or sleep/suspend with a value of `33`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Nvidia driver isn't remembering the backlight value even though your GNOME does. Let's work around this with a sleep hook:

1. Paste the following into `/etc/systemd/system/nvidia-backlight-sleep-askubuntu-1505827-1004020.service`

   ```ini
   [Unit]
   Description=Fix Nvidia backlight after suspend
   Before=sleep.target
   StopWhenUnneeded=yes

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   RemainAfterExit=yes
   ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "cat /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/actual_brightness > /run/previous_nv_backlight_brightness"
   ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "sleep 1; cat /run/previous_nv_backlight_brightness > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness"

   [Install]
   WantedBy=sleep.target
   ```
2. Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Run `sudo systemctl enable nvidia-backlight-sleep-askubuntu-1505827-1004020.service`

`actual_brightness` isn't the writable one so we need to use the `brightness` file. You can also adjust the `sleep 1` in case it doesn't work or if you want it to be restored quicker. `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-backlight@.service` is responsible for saving at shutdown/startup while the GPU driver itself is responsible for suspend/resume.

#### Alternative solution

If that doesn't work, we can hardcode more things:

1. Disable and remove the other solution
2. Paste the following into `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/nvidia-backlight-sleep-askubuntu-1505827-1004020`

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   case $1 in
     post)
       sleep 1
       echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness
       ;;
   esac
   ```
3. `sudo chmod 755 /lib/systemd/system-sleep/nvidia-backlight-sleep-askubuntu-1505827-1004020`

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work. I tried various `sleep` settings with values as high as `10`. What's interesting, however, is that I had to press the brightness key several times to get back to 100% instead of just once.

Comment: @mpboden What happens if you echo some number into /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness ? Is there an error?

Comment: `echo 50 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness` is successful without error. So my attempts to write to `actual_brightness` were wrong as you indicated, even when I allowed write access. With respect to this, I was misunderstanding how this works.

Comment: @mpboden I added an alternative solution

Comment: Your alternative solution isn't working either.

Comment: Oh I never thought anyone would want nouveau over proprietary

Comment: It's not that I intentionally wanted `nouveau`. It's just that when I installed Ubuntu on this laptop, I never found the need to update the driver. And ever since, I haven't had any issues until now. Thanks for your time and effort! Much appreciated nonetheless. :)